# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk', Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to make a GUI rock, paper, scissors game. Here's the CLI version:

```
import random

print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!")

rps = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
random_move = random.choice(rps)
print(random_move)

while True:
    attempt = input("Enter your attempt: ")
    if (attempt == random_move):
        print("We have a tie!")
        continue
    elif (attempt == "rock"):
        if (random_move == "scissors"):
            print("You smashed the computer's scissors with a rock!")
            break
        elif(random_move == "paper"):
            print("The computer wrapped your rock up in paper!")
            break
    elif (attempt == "paper"):
        if (random_move == "scissors"):
            print("The computer cut your paper in half with its scissors!")
            break
        elif (random_move == "rock"):
            print("You wrapped the computer's rock up in paper!")
            break
    elif(attempt == "scissors"):
        if (random_move == "paper"):
            print("You cut the computer's paper in half with your scissors!")
            break
        elif (random_move == "rock"):
            print("The computer smashed your scissors with its rock!")
            break
```

However, when implementing this in a GUI, I have decided to get rid of the loop to make things easier, and to only give the user one guess. It doesn't work, and nothing on Google gives me any clue as to how I can fix it. Please help.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as ttk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")

window_width = 300
window_height = 200

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

basic_label = tk.Label(root, text="Rock, Paper, Scissors")
basic_label.pack()

guess = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable="guess")
guess.pack()

def callback():
    rps = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    random_move = random.choice(rps)
    userguess = guess.get()
    #Uncomment the following two lines of code for easy mode.
    #print_move = ttk.Label(random_move)
    #print_move.pack()
    if (userguess == random_move):
        tie = ttk.Label(root, text="We have a tie!")
        tie.pack()
    elif (userguess == "rock"):
        if (random_move == "scissors"):
            smash = ttk.Label(root, text="You smashed the computer's scissors with a rock!")
            smash.pack()
        elif (random_move == "paper"):
            wrap = ttk.Label(root, text="The computer wrapped your rock up in paper!")
            wrap.pack()
    elif (userguess == "paper"):
        if (random_move == "scissors"):
            cut = ttk.Label(root, text="The computer cut your paper in half with its scissors!")
            cut.pack()
        elif (random_move == "rock"):
            wrap1 = ttk.Label(root, text="You wrapped the computer's rock up in paper")
            wrap1.pack()
    elif (userguess == "scissors"):
        if (random_move == "paper"):
            cut1 = ttk.Label(root, text="You cut the computer's paper in half with your scissors!")
            cut1.pack()
        elif (random_move == "rock"):
            smash1 = ttk.Label(root, text="The computer smashed your scissors with its rock!")
            smash1.pack()

button = ttk.Button(root, text="Guess!", command=callback)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Posting detailed error message would help greatly in debugging your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `print_move = ttk.Label(random_move)` should be `print_move = ttk.Label(root, text=random_move)`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I would advise you to simplify your code. You should never have more than one elif.

Also, you have a lot of repetition, try to find all the repetitions and factor them all together, Here is an example on how I  would have done it :

```
def check_winner(user_move, random_move):
    beating_table = {
        'rock': 'scissors',
        'paper': 'rock',
        'scissors': 'paper'
    }
    action = {
        'rock': ['smashed', 'scissors with a rock!'],
        'paper':['wrapped', 'rock up in paper!'] ,
        'scissors':['cut', 'paper in half with scissors!' ] 
    }
    # We use an associative array to know the winner of each
    # combination, and to generate the winner string.
    if (user_move == random_move):
        return 'We have a tie!'
    elif (beating_table[user_move] == random_move):
        act = action[user_move]
        return f'You {act[0]} the computer\'s {act[1]}'
    # If it is not a tie, and you're not the winner, then
    # The computer wins.
    act = action[random_move]
    return f'The computer {act[0]} your {act[1]}'


def callback():
    rps = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    random_move = random.choice(rps)
    userguess = guess.get()
    label = ttk.Label(root, text=check_winner(userguess, random_move))
    label.pack()
```

Concerning your error in particular, it would help to have the original error message, complete, with the stack-trace. Also try to rename your tk object (`root`) differently, I seems this already caused issues in the passed if you use the same name (root) somewhere else in your code.

Another odd thing in your code which may cause problems, is you're importing the same module twice with different alias and you use both:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as ttk
```

Does it help ?